# How is the id populated for a Backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I notice that all instances of Backbone models have an id that looks like this: id: `"/api/v1/item/36/"` This is the URL that corresponds to the model. Of course, I want the ID to be just 36. Is this a problem with the JSON that my API returns. Here is the JSON that my API returns:

```
{"created_at": "2012-04-24T22:09:41.683039", "id": "36", "name": "new", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/item/36/", "updated_at": "2012-04-24T22:51:23.664253", "user": "/api/v1/user/9/"}
```

Does it try to render the resource_uri as the ID? or is that completely separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone, by its own, doesn't assign any `id` to your Models.

One of two things: you either assign the `id` explicitly or Backbone take the `id` from the *response* of your first `POST` *request* to the server to *create* the Model.

Backbone does assign an *unique identifier* to each Model but this one is the [Model.cid](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-cid).

If your `Model.id` looks like `/api/v1/item/36/` is because you, somehow, have assigned this value explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate a model from this JSON the id will be 36. 
If you work with collections you need to specify the url: "/api/v1/item/", so the collection knows where to fetch/save the models.